# How to print output of Subprocess Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, output

```
`import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(
['/home/kadia/tensorflow/bazelbin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image',
'--graph=/home/kadia/Desktop/TrainedShadowModel-1/output_graph.pb',
'--labels=/home/kadia/Desktop/TrainedShadowModel-1/output_labels.txt',
'--output_layer=final_result',
'--input_layer=Mul',
'--image=/home/kadia/Desktop/2.jpg']`
```

How can I print the output from this? Output right now going in console. I want to save the output in file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    p = Popen(['/home/kadia/tensorflow/bazelbin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image',
'--graph=/home/kadia/Desktop/TrainedShadowModel-1/output_graph.pb',
'--labels=/home/kadia/Desktop/TrainedShadowModel-1/output_labels.txt',
'--output_layer=final_result',
'--input_layer=Mul',
'--image=/home/kadia/Desktop/2.jpg'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
    rc = p.returncode
```

Comment: I'm new to python. Can you formulate code for me which I can run, based on my process which I shared in Question.  I've tired but won't able to run it.

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you try like this? Assuming the command is correct